# Java Constructors and thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading, constructor

Literature talks about advertising a reference to an object before its constructor finished allocating and initializing its data structures. This usually involves putting it somewhere where other threads can see it prematurely. As I understand it, it involves an explicit act of advertising such as when using a Listener.

My question relates to the implementation of a constructor and the possibility of something similar happening. I can imagine that a constructor can be implemented with something similar to:

```
Type t = new Type(...);
```

An implementation in C might do something like:

```
t = malloc(sizeOf Type);
```

And then proceed to initialize all the fields.

If it can be implemented like this, then the reference t will be non-null, before the data is initialized. If another thread checks it for being non-null, it will then proceed to use it before it is fully initialized. The result will be mayhem.

I cannot find anything that says that you cannot implement it like this. I am probably missing something pretty basic in my understanding of the Java Memory Model. Is there anything that instructs JVM implementors not to do it like this?

Comment: The reference `t` will be `null` until the construction has completed.

Comment: `Type t = new Type();` is not _implementing_ a constructor, it's _calling_ a constructor. Are you specifically asking about the case where `t` is a field on some containing class?

Comment: It's not clear what you are actually asking about or what your question is.

Comment: Please check this blogpost https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/

Comment: If an answer has helped you solve your problem, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Another thread can't see the local variable `t`.

Answer (score 2):

Every once in a while, the thread-safely of Java object constructors comes up. More specifically, it's not so much about the process of object construction but rather the visibility of writes triggered by that process in relation to other threads.

What if a JVM implementation were to allocate memory for the new instance, store the new reference value and only then execute the constructor? What are the guarantees provided by the [Java memory model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) and would that represent a violation?

It's all about the actual reference assignment. Constructors themselves do not come with a guarantee that all writes happen before the write of the object reference. If the reference is not assigned to a `volatile` or `final` field, the JIT and/or the target CPU (in terms of memory reordering) are free to assign the reference before object construction. That's an optimization decision the JIT can easily make. In case of `volatile` or `final` fields, however, the situation is different as of Java 1.5.

A prominent example affected by constructor thread-safety is the double-checked locking pattern (lazy initialization not requiring a lock after the initialization phase), which, if implemented as follows, suffers from a concurrency issue and is **not** thread-safe. Another thread may see a partially constructed `Singleton` instance because the Java memory model does not mandate any specific memory ordering for normal reads and writes.

```
private Singleton singleton;

public Singleton getInstance() {
  if (singleton == null) {
    synchronized (this) {
      if (singleton == null) {
        singleton = new Singleton();
      }
    }
  }
  return singleton;
}
```

With Java 1.5, the memory model was changed in respect to `volatile` and `final` fields. With the new model, volatile writes have release semantics and volatile reads have acquire semantics. Provided `volatile` is used for `singleton`, this pattern works as expected because the memory model guarantees the expected order of events.

```
tmp = new Singleton();
// implicit release memory barrier caused by volatile
singleton = tmp;
```

Release semantics prevent memory reordering of any read or write that precedes it in program order with any write that follows it in program order. This is equivalent to a combination of `LoadStore` and `StoreStore` memory barriers. Consequently, reads and writes belonging to `Singleton` object construction must not move after the volatile `singleton` write.

```
tmp = singleton;
// implicit acquire memory barrier caused by volatile
if (tmp == null) {
  synchronized (this) 
    if (tmp == null) {
```

Acquire semantics prevent memory reordering of any read that precedes it in program order with any read or write that follows it in program order. This is equivalent to a combination of `LoadLoad` and `LoadStore` memory barriers. Consequently, `Singleton` reads and writes must not move before the volatile `singleton` read.

It's worth noting that in all versions of Java, volatile reads and writes are totally-ordered. All threads observe the same volatile read/write order. To achieve that, either a volatile write precedes a `StoreLoad` memory barrier or a volatile read follows a `StoreLoad` memory barrier. On x86, only the `StoreLoad` memory barrier emit and instruction, other barriers have to be considered during JIT reordering.

Similarly, the semantics in terms of `final` fields have changed with Java 1.5. [JSR133](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/memory_model-1.0-pfd-spec-oth-JSpec), which introduced the memory model changes, used the following example to illustrate the problem:

```
class FinalFieldExample {
  final int x;
  int y;
  static FinalFieldExample f;

  public FinalFieldExample() {
    x = 3;
    y = 4;
  }
  static void writer() {
    f = new FinalFieldExample();
  }
  static void reader() {
    if (f != null) {
      int i = f.x;
      int j = f.y;
    }
  }
}
```

Given two threads, thread A calling `writer()` and thread B calling `reader()`, the natural assumption would be that thread B is guaranteed to see the values `3` for `i` and and `0` or `4` for `j`. Due to reordering, thread B could see `0` instead - a clear violation of the premise of `final`, not in terms of the original memory model but in respect to the higher-level contract of `final` to represent immutable constant values.

To address this, Java 1.5 and later specify this guarantee:

> [...] A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed to see the correctly initialized values for that object's final fields. [...]

The implementation uses a `StoreStore` memory barrier to prevent the write of `x` from moving after the assignment of `f`. Default values of `y` can still be observed.

In Java 9, [`java.lang.invoke.VarHandle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html) was introduced to provide access to acquire/release and volatile semantics. `VarHandle` is comparable to C++11's `std::atomic` in that it provides atomic primitives and memory ordering control including explicit memory barriers.

The Java object constructor is not inherently thread-safe. With the help of `volatile`, `final`, and `VarHandle`, required guarantees can be established. For most common use cases, alternative patterns exist that do not require dealing with these kinds of low-level details. Whenever possible, prefer not to roll your own lock-free code to reduce code complexity and maximize the probability of correctness.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination. I've been looking for this explaination for sometime now.

Comment: Just to note, if you have at least one final field write, the final fields semantics extend to every other field written in constructor.
Reference: https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/#_safe_initialization

Answer (score 0):

A direct violation of your hypothetical implementation of an allocator is in [JLS 17.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5) which enforces that any seen references to an object see all its final fields correctly initialized: "A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed to see the correctly initialized values for that object's final fields." The allocator you made would fail this invariant.

Comment: No. 15.26.1 does not mention any implications on other threads. This concerns sequential execution, the LHS must never be assigned an incomplete RHS. The same is true for C++ and other languages, yet this does not imply that other threads cannot see partially constructed objects. If the memory model does not guarantee that, there's no such guarantee. 17.5 only applies to final fields. In that case, however, you're right in that the initialization of final fields has memory ordering implications and can be used to implement double-checked locking, for example.

Comment: If that was the case, double-checked locking in Java would have to work out-of-the-box.

Comment: My quoting of the two different sections is to provide counterexamples to this potential implementation in how they don't adhere to the documented assignment evaluation and handling of the visibility of final fields in the JLS. I could see how in the context of the question you would infer that I was saying that the assignment evaluation order would prevent partially constructed objects from being visible to other threads but that was not my intent. It was simply to show the implementation was not adhering to the JLS.